# CakePHP add method confused

Tags: php, cakephp

On my CakePHP site I use a table called `portfolio` I tell Cake this in the model to get around the automated plural nonsense with the following code:

```
class Portfolio extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Portfolio';

    var $useTable = 'portfolio';
}
```

This works fine except when trying to add a new portfolio item as even though the url is fine at /portfolio/add/ the form itself has an action of /portfolios/add/ which breaks the app.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

it's much better and easier to follow CakePHP conventions

that would save you a lot of time !!

your problem is just an example..

by time, you will face more similar problems !!

i strongly recommend that you follow the conventions of CakePHP

one of them is "use plural names for tables"

Answer (score 0):

Ended up hacking it like so:

`echo $this->Form->create(null, array('url' => array('controller' => 'portfolio', 'action' => 'add')));`

Really hate how CakePHP adds a dam s to everything!

Comment: Why don't you use portfolios? It makes more sense. Table names should be in pluar because they are a collection of objects like portfolios.